# Harry Potter fanfiction where he perfects a sweet potion

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I read a *Harry Potter* fan-fiction a while ago where Harry perfects a sweet potion. I vaguely remember the potion being called "Fairy Floss" or something like that. I'm pretty sure it was either Drarry or at least Slytherin Harry. It was multi-chaptered and pretty long, I think.

The original potion was a children's candy most people above the age of 5 found unbearably sweet and Harry tried to fix it so it was nicer.

Comment: Welcome, Ana! See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11924/102999) to help improve your question. This question is very broad; for starters, when did you read this? Where?

Comment: I'm unsure why this is being voted to close as too broad. Can the people VTCing as such provide at least two examples of a matching story? If not, it is not too broad.

Answer (score 1):

wait, just found it! Damn, 2 days searching and when i finally give up there it is. It's [Lost for love by Queen MiMi of Wonderland](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9359461/1/Lost-For-Love).

turns it it was actually a Twin-who-lived Tom/Harry fanfic - i remembered this one much better than i thought, just didn't remember that this scene belonged to it. it is unfortunately incomplete.